# When HTML canvas is inside svg through foreignObject I lose all svg interactivity

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a svg map which consists of polygons. On polygon hover there is tooltip showing country name. As well each polygon have a circle representing capital and on hover name is shown. 
I want to make mouse drawing option over the map (curve, line, circle, rectangle...) so I used canvas inside foreignObject in svg.

Svg is in html as object:

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Canvas is in svg inside foreignObject:

```
<foreignObject height="988" width="1575" y="0" x="215">
 <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="960" height="1575"></canvas>
 </span>
</foreignObject>
```

Drawing with mouse move:

```
var canvas = svgDoc.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var started = false;
function ev_mousemove (ev) {
  var x, y;
  x=ev.pageX;
  y=ev.pageY;
if (!started) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  started = true;
} else {
  context.lineTo(x, y);
  context.stroke();
}}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
```

The problem is that canvas overlap my svg, I can draw with mouse in canvas but I lose all interactivity of svg (tooltip, hover). It's like canvas is active layer over svg who is locked and visible. How I can make svg and canvas work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with not using canvas. Using d3.js library it is possible to draw directly over svg.

Comment: I was looking for something like this, could you please post a small example of your solution?